# Android Virtual Keyboard and Listener reverting values?

Tags: java, android

I have a custom list view, and an OnItemClickListener for it. I have a TextView listViewRightText variable that tracks a textView on the right side of each row of the listview.

The idea is to have an AlertDialog with a TextView, and when the user hits OK, the listViewRightText item will change values. This is the code for that part.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
....

final EditText input = new EditText(ActivityMainScreen.this);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

                new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityMainScreen.this)
                        .setTitle("Enter " + listViewLeftText.getText())
                        .setView(input)
                        .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                 // Do Nothing
                                }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            listViewRightText.setText(input.getText());

                             }

                }).show();
```

This works as expected on the emulator when using the hardware keyboard.

I tested it on my phone with virtual keyboard, and noticed that the new values will appear properly for a fraction of a second, and then revert (fade) to the old values.

The same thing happens in the emulator if I enable the virtual keyboard.

I've tried not hitting "done"/hitting "done" on the virtual keyboard before pressing "OK" on the dialog box, and it is the same behavior.

I Googled and didn't come across anything about this. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure WHY this was working with the hardware keyboard, but I found that the reason it wasn't working with the virtual keyboard was that I needed to set the text TextView through the custom adapter vs. setting it directly.